# Substitute text in a file with sed from environment variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file with this content:

```
$ cat text.txt 
my email is $email
```

I can replace `$email` like this:

```
sed -i -e 's/$email/test@gmail.com/g' text.txt
```

However, I want to replace `$email` with the value from an environment variable, like this:

```
sed -i -e 's/$email/$EMAIL/g' text.txt
```

However, it's not working, this is what the file is showing:

```
my email is $EMAIL
```

What am I doing wrong?

I cannot use envsubst as I am running this command inside a Docker container whose underlying images does not have envsubst installed

Comment: `sed -e 's/$email/'"$EMAIL"'/g'`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `sed` script in double quotes to allow expansion of the `$EMAIL` variable, and escape the `$` so it's treated as a literal character:

```
$ EMAIL='test@gmail.com'

$ sed "s/\$email/${EMAIL}/g" text.txt
my email is test@gmail.com

$ sed -i "s/\$email/${EMAIL}/g" text.txt
$ cat text.txt
my email is test@gmail.com
```